# Shortcut to move to a specific part of a text file

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, sublimetext2, sublimetext, sublime-text-plugin

I'd like to create a keyboard shortcut (such as <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>) that automatically moves the cursor to the line after the occurence of a fixed text, such as `&todo`.

Example:

```
foo 
bar
&todo
fix bug #783
blah
blah2
```

Pressing <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> would automatically move the cursor to the line beginning with `fix ...`.

Currently I'm doing it like this:

- <kbd>CTRL</kbd> <kbd>F</kbd>
- enter `&todo`, <kbd>ENTER</kbd>
- <kbd>ESCAPE</kbd> (closes the `Search` bottom panel)
- <kbd>HOME</kbd>
- <kbd>DOWN ARROW</kbd> (moves to next line)

but this requires too many actions.

**How to do that in a single key shortcut?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best solution is it use a plugin to do that.

The plugin below does what you require. It will find the next occurrence of `pattern` (i.e. the `&todo` marker) below the current cursor position, move the cursor to the line below it, and centre that position in the window. If the `pattern` is not found below the current cursor position it will search again from the top of the buffer providing a *wrap around* feature.

Copy and paste the following Python code into a buffer and save it in your Sublime Text config `User` folder as `GoToPattern.py`.

```py
import sublime
import sublime_plugin

class GotoPatternCommand(sublime_plugin.TextCommand):

    def run(self, edit, pattern):

        sels = self.view.sel()
        # Optional flags; see API.
        flags = sublime.LITERAL | sublime.IGNORECASE
        start_pos = sels[0].end() if len(sels) > 0 else 0
        find_pos = self.view.find(pattern, start_pos, flags)

        if not find_pos and start_pos > 0:
            # Begin search again at the top of the buffer; wrap around
            # feature, i.e. do not stop the search at the buffer's end.
            find_pos = self.view.find(pattern, 0, flags)

        if not find_pos:
            sublime.status_message("'{}' not found".format(pattern))
            return

        sels.clear()
        sels.add(find_pos.begin())
        self.view.show_at_center(find_pos.begin())
        row, col = self.view.rowcol(find_pos.begin())
        self.view.run_command("goto_line", {"line": row + 2})
        # Uncomment for: cursor to the end of the line.
        # self.view.run_command("move_to", {"to": "eol"})
```

Add key bindings:

```js
// The pattern arg, i.e. "&todo", can be changed to anything you want
// and other key bindings can also be added to use different patterns.
{"keys": ["???"], "command": "goto_pattern", "args": {"pattern": "&todo"}}
```

Add a Command Palette entry to `Default.sublime-commands` if you want:

```
{"caption": "GoToPattern: &todo", "command": "goto_pattern", "args": {"pattern": "&todo"}},
```

These links may be useful to you [ST v. 2 API](https://www.sublimetext.com/docs/2/api_reference.html) and [ST v. 3 API](https://www.sublimetext.com/docs/3/api_reference.html).

P.S. Did you know that Sublime Text has bookmarks? [Just in case you didn't.]

Answer (score 0):

The [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55308430/1422096) is really better and I'm finally using it.

For reference, here an old solution I used: first create a `gototodo.py` file in `"C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\Sublime Text 2\Packages\User\"` containing:

```
import sublime, sublime_plugin

class GototodoCommand(sublime_plugin.TextCommand):
    def run(self, edit):
        contents = self.view.substr(sublime.Region(0, self.view.size()))  # https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20182008/sublime-text-3-api-get-all-text-from-a-file
        a = contents.find('&todo')
        cursors = self.view.sel()
        cursors.clear()
        location = sublime.Region(a, a)
        cursors.add(location)
        self.view.show_at_center(location)

        (row, col) = self.view.rowcol(self.view.sel()[0].begin())  # go to the next line
        self.view.run_command("goto_line", {"line": row+2})
```

Then add this in `"C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\Sublime Text 2\Packages\User\Default (Windows).sublime-keymap"`:

```
{ "keys": ["ctrl+t"], "command": "gototodo" }
```

Done!

Comment: No need for `import subprocess`. Your plugin will only ever move the cursor to the first occurrence of "&todo".

Comment: Sublime Text version 3 has been stable for 5+ years and is almost certainly a much better choice than the very old version 2 which was last updated in 2013. Version 3 has been out of beta for several years and it is the default download on [SublimeText.com](https://www.sublimetext.com/3).

Comment: @mattst You're right about `subprocess`, I first included it because of something totally different (nearly another plugin), but you're right, it should be removed. I'll edit now.

Comment: @mattst About ST version: would this code here run perfectly on ST3 or would a few modifications be required here?

Comment: No modifications needed, it works fine, I tested it to make sure. Note that ST2 and ST3 can both be installed on the same computer while you make the transition from version 2 to 3.